# How to get request contents in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I have the following code which posts file to ASP.net page:

```
using (var Client = new WebClient())
    Client.UploadFile("http://localhost:1625/Upload.aspx", @"TestFile.csv");
```

On the server page I read the contents of the request:

```
        var Contents = new byte[Request.InputStream.Length];
        Request.InputStream.Read(Contents, 0, (int)Request.InputStream.Length);
```

This is what I get in the contents:

```
-----------------------8cf2bdc76fe2b40
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="TestFile.csv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

1;Test 1
2;Test 2
3;Test 3
4;Test 4
5;Test 5
-----------------------8cf2bdc76fe2b40--
```

Actual file contents are just `1;Test 1 ... 5;Test 5`.
My question is how to get only file contents and not the whole request with headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, get the posted file first:

```
 {
    HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;
    HttpPostedFile file = files[0];
    int filelength = file.ContentLength;
    byte[] input = new byte[filelength ];
    file.InputStream.Read(input, 0, filelength );

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with the [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h55b6cak) class. It has a property [Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files) which states holding the files uploaded by the client.
I did not test this...

Answer (score 0):

you can use NameValueCollection to getting request content in ASP.Net:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
string firstname, lastname;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtFirstName"]))
{
  firstname = nvc["txtFirstName"];
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["txtLastName"]))
{
  lastname = nvc["txtLastName"];
}
```

here `txtFirstName` and `txtLastName` both are the Names of the controls of previous page.

Comment: I think you are answering some other question.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var Content = Client.UploadFile("http://localhost:1625/Upload.aspx", @"TestFile.csv");
string fileContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Contents));
```